Relationship between Altimeter and Transponder
I'm wondering if there's a relationship between Altimeter, Mode C and Transponder. I'm asking because I understand that the Mode C transmits pressure altitude and aircrafts identification code to ATC and nearby aircrafts. If this is correct may I know how these components are connected to each other.

This question is similar to: Where does the transponder read altitude, or does ATC get it from radar?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. -- see in particular my answer on that question.

This is really multiple questions in one, so while I suggested that the "what is Mode C" question is is a duplicate of another (really several) on this site, the others may not be... but they're all relatively quick and relatively connected, so here's a brief answer. I don't have the time to make it more brief.
You asked about:

Altimeter
Mode C
Transponder

The altimeter and the transponder are physical devices installed in an aircraft. Mode C is a communications/encoding protocol used by the transponder.

The altimeter is a device which indicates to the pilot what their altitude is. The altitude indicated is referenced to a certain altimeter setting. If the pilot has not set the altimeter to the proper setting, the indicated altitude will not be accurate.
The transponder can send two distinct pieces of information to ATC (and possibly other surrounding transponders), depending on which one the ATC radar has requested: Either a specific identifying 12-bit number, or the aircraft's pressure altitude encoded into Gillham code (a modified Gray code). The identifying number is called a "Mode A" response and the encoded pressure altitude is a "Mode C" response.

The transponder uses an "encoder" to translate the pressure altitude into the proper Gillham code. This encoder is distinct from the altimeter used by the pilot: The pilot can spin the altimeter setting up or down and that will change what they see on their instrument, but it will NOT affect the Mode C and so will NOT change what ATC sees on the radar scope.

Thanks its clear now
